# Difference between spawn/1 and spawn/3

Tags: elixir

I believe I have read somewhere that there is a difference between using `spawn/1` and `spawn/3` when it comes to hot reloading but I can't find any complete info on the subject. So I wonder if there is actually a difference and if there is, then what is it? Some example would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the two is that `spawn/1` makes a local function call, while `spawn/3` makes a "fully qualified" function call.

When you load a new version of a module, the old version is still kept around, and any process that was executing in the old version keeps doing that.  The exception is if the process performs a "fully qualified" function call, including the module name: in that case, the newest version of the code is always used.

For example, with this module:

```
defmodule Foo do

  def start_loop do
    spawn(fn -> loop end)
  end

  def loop do
    receive do
      :foo ->
        spawn &print_foo/0
        loop
      :reload ->
        Foo.loop
    end
  end

  def print_foo do
    IO.puts "foo 1"
  end
end
```

we can start a process, and every time we send `:foo` to it, it spawns another process that prints `foo 1`:

```
iex(1)> c("foo.ex")
[Foo]
iex(2)> p = Foo.start_loop
#PID<0.68.0>
iex(3)> send p, :foo
foo 1
:foo
iex(4)> send p, :foo
foo 1
:foo
```

Now, if we modify the module to print `foo 2` instead, and recompile and reload it, there is no immediate change:

```
iex(5)> c("foo.ex")       
warning: redefining module Foo (current version loaded from Elixir.Foo.beam)
  foo.ex:1

[Foo]
iex(6)> send p, :foo
foo 1
:foo
```

Only when we tell the process to "reload", by making a fully qualified call to the module, do we get the new version:

```
iex(7)> send p, :reload
:reload
iex(8)> send p, :foo   
foo 2
:foo
```

---

Of course, if you use `spawn/1` with a function that just makes a fully qualified call, the difference disappears:

```
spawn(fn -> Foo.print_foo end)
```